# django two filter with different key on merge with same key name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

In django i have two query like :

```
First = User.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).values('first_id','first_name')
Second = User.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).values('second_id','second_name')
combined_results = list(chain(competitorFirst, competitorSecond))
```

After this i am getting output like:

```
{'first_id': '1', 'first_name': 'Hornets'}
{'second_id': '2', 'second_name': 'corto'}
```

what i actually want is like:

```
{'id': '1', 'name': 'Hornets'}
{'id': '2', 'name': 'corto'}
```

can anyone please help how can i solve this .

Comment: Feels like your database is not normalized... Instead of making such weird queries normalize your database schema (models).

Comment: Its seems like you have an issue stemming from your model design. If I'm mistaken you should only have `id` and `name` in your model and multiple entries should be listed as rows rather than additional columns: `second_id` `second_name`. This is based on what you **want it too look like**

Answer (score 0):

You are ultimatly chaining queryies, so why not just convert them to dictionary, normalize them and then chain them:

```
name_map = {'first_name': 'name', 'second_name': 'name', 'first_id': 'id', 'second_id':'id'}

def rename_dict(d):
   return dict((name_map[key], value) for (key, value) in d.items())

competitorFirst = map(rename_dict,  list(User.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).values('first_id','first_name'))) 

competitorSecond = map(rename_dict,  list(User.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).values('second_id','second_name')))

combined_results = list(chain(competitorFirst, competitorSecond))
```

**Update:** I think you should look into your model design, because if you have two competitors then it would be better to have a seperate table for that competion, and use combined results. For example:

```
class Competition(models.Model):
   first_competitor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='first')
   second_competitor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='second')
```

You can consider ManyToMany fields as well if you have more than two competitors.

Comment: yep, noticed that after answering, added an update section as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.db.models import F

First = User.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).values(id=F('first_id'), name=F('first_name'))
Second = User.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).values(id=F('second_id'), name=F('second_name'))
combined_results = list(chain(competitorFirst, competitorSecond))
```

use F to set the name.